# When to save the state of an app

Tags: android, database, storage, lifecycle

I am building an Android game. Now, I am saving all changes of the user state (matches in SQLite, user's preferences in SharedPreferences, and other data in files) in the `onDestroy()` method of the main fragment (that fragment should be alive all the time and can open other activities, such as a the account fragment or playing fragment).

If I exit the app via **Back** button, everything works fine since `onDestroy()` of main fragment is called.

The problem is when I exit via **Home** button, or when main fragment is killed from OS. In these cases, `onDestroy()` isn't called, so the state of the game isn't saved.

I know that I can resolve that if I save the game in the `onPause()` instead of `onDestroy()`, since it is always called. But the storage operation, in my case, is very big (SQLite + SharedPreferences + files, a lot of data) and do that in `onPause()` means inefficiency.

Is there any other way to manage this?

Comment: Create a service pass all the data in the intent when onPause() is called , then do the rest in that service. i haven't tried it just an idea as the service will offload your main work from activity to background

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this solution - http://nisha113a5.blogspot.com/2012/01/intercept-home-key-android.html?

Try to hook Home button pressing, and at this moment save user state.

Comment: Anyway, intercept Home button is insufficient, since I can simply press a bar notification for exiting the application.